# Match Columns and Calculate Third Column Np. Where Issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas DataFrames. 
Dataframe 1:

```
League Ab.    Year      G/G Avg     A/G Avg    
League A      2018       0.35         0.58
League B      2018       0.68         0.72
League A      2019       0.37         0.66
League B      2019       0.65         0.68
```

DataFrame 2:

```
Player        Year    League Ab.     G/G    A/G
Player A      2018    League A      0.02   0.03
Player B      2018    League B      0.52   0.34
Player C      2018    League A      0.68   0.26
Player A      2019    League A      0.12   0.22 
Player B      2019    League B      0.55   0.31
Player C      2019    League A      0.71   0.34
```

What I am trying to do is calculate two new columns in DataFrame 2 labeled "Normalized G/G" and Normalized "A/G". These are calculated by multiplying the player's G/G by their league's G/G Avg for the given year and then dividing it by their league's G/G Avg from the previous year. Repeat this process for A/G.

I currently have a function that uses np.where to accomplish this:

```
def normalize_league_points(df1, df2):
    df1['Normalized Goals'] = np.where((df1['League Ab.'] == df2['League Ab.']) & (df1['Season End Year'] == df2['Season End Year']), df1['G/G'] / df2['LG G/G Avg'])
    df1['Normalized Goals'] = np.where((df1['League Ab.'] == df2['League Ab.']) & (df1['Season End Year'] == (df2['Season End Year']-1)), df1['G/G'] * df2['LG G/G Avg'])
```

However, this is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Or how do I fix my error? Thanks.

Comment: `df1['League Ab.'] == df2['League Ab.']` This is the problem. This comparison makes no sense, `df1` and `df2` aren't the same length, so how would this even work? I think you are looking to `merge` the information from `df1` onto `df2` so that you can do the comparison there?

Comment: So if I merge the two @ALollz , how would I calculate the normalized goals? 
```df1['Normalized Goals'] = (df1['G/G'] / df1['LG G/G Avg']) * (df1['LG G/G Avg'] -1)?```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in df1['League Ab.'] == df2['League Ab.']

This comparison is between two Series objects that doesn't have the same length.

In order to get the results you are looking for, you should first merge df1 onto df2

After merge you will get a result DataFrame that looks like

```
Player        Year    League Ab.     G/G    A/G     G/G Avg     A/G Avg
Player A      2018    League A      0.02   0.03 .   0.35         0.58
Player B      2018    League B      0.52   0.34 .   0.68         0.72
Player C      2018    League A      0.68   0.26 .   0.35         0.58
Player A      2019    League A      0.12   0.22     0.37         0.66
Player B      2019    League B      0.55   0.31 .   0.65         0.68
Player C      2019    League A      0.71   0.34 .   0.37         0.66
```

After that you can calculate the two columns you wanted to calulate directly in this result DataFrame

The code to do that is :

```
# Merge the two DataFrames
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Leangue AB','Year')])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I complete the merge how do I calculate the columns?So far, this is what I have to calculate them:
```merged_data['Normalized Goals'] = (merged_data['G/G'] / merged_data['G/G Avg'])  *``` But I don't know how to multiply it by the previous year's average.

Comment: You can do a second merge where you create a previous year column and indicators and merge with them again, and like that you can calculate the normalized averages in one line because you'll have all the needed values. but also you can avoid all of this and use a loop into the first data frame row per row and query the first data frame for the needed values to calculate. The second approach will be computationaly heavy thought.